# Get JSON from PHP (Trying to access array offset on value of type null)

Tags: php, json

sorry for my english it's not my main language.

I'm trying to access a fortnite api, and after multiple tries, and a lot of searching, i can't figure out whats wrong with it.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://fnbr.co/api/shop",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "x-api-key: -------------"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$getinfo = json_decode($response, true);

var_dump(json_decode($response));
var_dump(json_decode($response, true));


foreach ( $getinfo['data']['featured'] as $item){
    echo $item['name'];
}
?>
```

It's always giving me the "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" but my code was always working until today!

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you see in the `var_dump`?

Comment: debug.php:27:null

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a response? What is in `$response`?

Comment: I had my code for 2 months, only yesterday that didn't work, i've checked the json file that i receive my information from, and it's still the same, the error is always the same "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"

Comment: So, i've downgraded the php version, and it's now working.